# WCF Data Services with Custom Entities

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a set of custom entities which reflect the business representation of data.  Then I also have a set of entities that map 1-to-1 to the database that represent the storage of the data.  My business layer converts between the 2 types and performs any other logic needed.  I only expose the custom objects through my service interface.

From what I can tell I cannot use WCF Data Services.  Data services

1. need to be bound directly to a db source (or some slight abstraction of the direct db connection) and,
2. that results in using the data entities.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't see any way to use WCF Data Services and its built-in queryability with custom entities while using my business layer.

Comment: For the record, WCF Data Services is very naive. I have a base class with the properties I want to expose in my feed and a child class with additional properties. When WCF-DS goes to serialize to ATOM it attempts to serialize the properties in my child class! It's reflection algorithm is not looking only at the properties in the class type I am handing it.

Comment: Data Services can also apparently not match-up an interface with its concrete type. If you return an interface type from your Entity properties like this: IQueryable<ISomething> it returns this error: <m:error>
    <m:code></m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Internal Server Error. The type 'SomeClass' is not a complex type or an entity type.</m:message>
  </m:error>

Answer (score 2):

I do not necessarily agree with that. If you look at the Architecture Overview in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794.aspx you see two other options next to the EF / DB connectivity. You can have Data Service Providers that just take an alternative (your custom) information model made up of queryable CLR classes and expose them using WCF data services.

So if you create your Business Layer using this approach, your custom entities can just as easy be exposed with WCF data services.

Comment: I should say that I did get Data Services working with my Business Entities.  I have a custom REST service and I essentially want to expose that functionality as OData.  Indeed I actually got Data Services working by calling into my existing REST endpoints.  The problem is if I want to filter my orders, I have to get all orders from my REST service and then filter them, which is a very heavy proposition.  Ideally I want the filtering to occur at the DB level, but I don't think that's possible using my exiting Business and Data Access Layers.

Comment: IMHO, your custom Business Entities have full control on the server side to do whatever they need to do to answer the OData queries. Since these queries allow to include filter statement, aren't your custom entities capable of of processing that filter action on the server side?

Comment: Kind of.  I guess that's my question.  Data Services takes care of parsing the query parameters, building the query, and executing it against my IQueryable properties.  What I would need to do is to be able to parse the query parameters myself and pass them into my DAL so that it could be executed against my queries.  Correct?  If I do that then what is Data Services doing for me?

Comment: Providing you a single standards based OData web-enabled interface instead of you having to create dedicated services operations and data contracts. That is worth something ...

Comment: Instead of parsing the query parameters, you can implement your own IQueryable and write a visitor to convert the expression tree into whatever your DAL understands. This is better since this abstracts you from the ODATA protocol. You need not worry about $filter, $orderby syntax and converting simple expressions into your DAL is not that hard.

Comment: Thanks Pratik. This is where I was attempting to go as of late. The problem I have is that I'm using Subsonic ActiveRecord which doesn't generate POCOs. The ActiveRecord Entities blow up the data services reflection algorithms. I tried creating both a base class and an interface on my ActiveRecord entities to only expose my properties that map to columns, which should have worked, but the DS implementation is so naive, in my opinion, that this solution fails. IMO, they built WCF-DS to work with EF and forgot about other data access solutions.